# Problem installing "Clone Hero"

Tags: games

I'm new in Linux world but I really like It.
Recently i tryed to install a game named "clone Hero" you can find here https://clonehero.net/releases/v0.22.5/#
I can't understand how to install the tar.gz file.
I've extract all, but in terminal I can't proceed the ./config command ...can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract files from .tar.gz archive in Files browser, right-click the archive and select `Extract Here` menu item.

To run `clonehero` in elementary OS, first you need to set Execute permission for its executable:

- in Files, go to the extracted folder (`clonehero-linux`);
- select `clonehero` executable, right-click it and click `Properties` menu item;
- in the dialog window, press `Permissions` tab;
- press `Execute` button in `Owner` row;
- close the window and double-click `clonehero` executable.

Comment: Ok, now When I press the executable just exit and return on the desktop...⁉️

Comment: You mean, you have given the `clonehero` "execute" permission, and now, when you double click it in Files, it quits? (Does it fail to start, or starts and then quits to desktop?..) What happens when you start the executable via Terminal command (`path-to-file/clonehero`)?

Comment: launch with ./clonehero from the directory location

Comment: Found path: /home/paolo/Documenti/Clonehero/clonehero
Mono path[0] = '/home/paolo/Documenti/Clonehero/clonehero_Data/Managed'Mono config path = '/home/paolo/Documenti/Clonehero/clonehero_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Preloaded 'ScreenSelector.so'
Preloaded 'libbass.so'
Preloaded 'libdiscord-rpc.so'
Unable to preload the following plugins:
 libbass_fx.so
Display 0 '0': 1024x600 (primary device).
Loading player data from /home/paolo/Documenti/Clonehero/clonehero_Data/data.unity3d
Logging to /home/paolo/.config/unity3d/srylain Inc_/Clone Hero/Player.log

Comment: ...unable to preload the plugins...?

Comment: Fail to start and appear Pop up "job ended"

Comment: When I start the app in Terminal from its directory via `./clonehero` command, I get the same output as you, but the app does start and seems to work. I am able to start it with a double-click in Files too. Have you set 'Execute' permission for this app as described in the answer above?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure OpenGL is working, or else clone hero will open and just close again with an error about libbass_fx.so